# FMX 3D and fopen() function

Tags: c++, firemonkey, c++builder, fopen

New to C++ Builder 10.4. Migrating from XE4.
A line of code fopen() that works fine in the old environment
`InputFileHandle = fopen(FileName, "rb");`
does not return a valid pointer in the FMX 3D environment for a file in the same directory that the project is running.
I'd appreciate if you can give me a solution for that.

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. For parts removed, please see the [help on chit chat](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Comment: (I don't think Embarcadero FireMonkey contributes here.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to for check which error occur

```
#include <errno.h>
....
FILE *InputFileHandle;
 
if ((InputFileHandle = fopen(FileName, "rb")) == NULL)
   printf(" %s \n", strerror(errno));
```

I can see only two possible trouble:

- Permission error, you'll have to fix the file permission.
- file does not exist meaning your new framework change the current directory.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The file security attribute is "Full Control" . So apparently there is no permission issue here, while the error message specifies the second matter that is the "framework change the current directory". I am wondering why this happens to begin with and secondly how to control the FMX environment to stop that? I shall mention that while in FMX 3D environment, I am writing the code to work in Windows Desktop. No IOS yet. Regards;

Comment: on the above answer, the second statement is: file does not exist meaning your new framework change the current directory

Comment: on the above answer, the second statement is: "file does not exist meaning your new framework change the current directory". why and how does that happen without my permission or request!? the file is physically located in the same directory! how does the FMX environment see this if you may? I am stuck since first thing I need to to is open my file and process the information in the file that is not happening here!?

Comment: I have tried the same issue with the following options too: From Welcome Page>Create a new Multi-Device Application C++>Blank Application as well, with the same result and the pointer to the file is returning NULL!?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you PHE for the answer and the clue you posted for my question. I checked the permissions on the file and they are accessible as needed. The issue was the "change of current directory" and that was causing the file not to be recognized. One solid answer is to specify the path to the file from the root directory( this could be cumbersome for long file paths!). For windows path to be recognized you shall specify forward-slash twice in the related string to be decoded properly, like this "C://dir1//dir2//....//filename". Regards

Comment: The above issue got resolved when I moved the target file to the Wim32\Debug directory for the RAD studio, FMX system to recognize the file and create the necessary pointer to the file for later access to it. This should have been mentioned in one of the RAD, FMX environment documents!?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you PHE for the answer and the clue you posted for my question. I checked the permissions on the file and they are accessible as needed. The issue was the "change of current directory" and that was causing the file not to be recognized. One solid answer is to specify the path to the file from the root directory( this could be cumbersome for long file paths!). For the windows path to be recognized you shall specify backward-slash twice in the related string to be decoded properly, like this "C:\dir1\dir2\....\filename". Regards